# Как переключать стили css между устройствами

Tags: javascript, html, css, useragent

Как переключать стили web-страницы между телефоном и планшетом с помощью user agent?

Пример:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) {
          document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/phone.css" type="text/css" />');/*стиль для мобильной версии*/
}else{
          document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" type="text/css" />');/*стиль для полноэкранной версии*/
}
```

Comment: Если различие не в "тач функции", а именно в определении мобильный/десктоп, то я бы сказал, что тут требуется библиотека. Тут надо определять разнообразные вхождения подстрок, при чем для разных устройств разные и постоянно меняются ввиду того, что устройств становится все больше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо,вспомнил про библиотеку device.js, через нее и сделал.